WhatsApp Flows Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'. The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded
We are getting the following error in WhatsApp flows:
"Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'. The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."
This occurs after "on-select-action" is executed and the information from the server is refreshing the screen.
We have dynamic data in the form of arrays that is updated from the server depending on the option selected on the dropdown.
       "Auto_Version":{ "type": "array", "items": { "type": "object", "properties": { "id": { "type": "string" }, "title": { "type": "string" } } }, "__example__": [ { "id": "1_SOA", "title": "Selecciona una opcion" } ] },
Then we get the following message back to the server :
"error": "",
"error_message": "Error: server is not available or unexpected error occurred"
The flows were working fine without a problem and all of a sudden started failing.
Any idea why this might be happening?
We tried reorganising the json (), changing versions of graph (we tried 15.0, 18.0 and 20.0) and versions in the json (3.0 and 3.1).
Nothing seems to work.
